# write vscode extension that changes the editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Im writing my own extension where I have a command that makes some changes within a range. I use:

```
let edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
let edits = [];    
let textEdit = vscode.TextEdit.replace(symbol.location.range, newString);
edits.push(textEdit);
edit.set(uri, edits);
```

I can see that newString has all the changes I have made but it is not reflected in the editor. It might be that newString has a larger range than the old range. Could that be the problem?

Regards
Håkan